# How to add an image as background image inline in Django

Tags: html, css, django

I know there are a lot of entries about how to use the staic files in Django and how to add them into html frame. I have searched 2 hours and tried every solution, but nothing worked for me!

I want to set the image as a background in a li-element. I tried all of the following:

```
<li style="background-image: url({% static \'images/start1.JPG\'});">
<li style="background-image: url('{% static &ldquo;images/start1.JPG&ldquo;}');">
<li style="background-image: url('{% static &quot;images/start1.JPG&quot;}');">
<li style="background-image: url('{% static \"images/start1.JPG\"}');">
<li style="background-image: '/static/images/start1.JPG';">
```

I'm probably just making a small misstake, but I cannot find it, I would really appreciate some help.

I tried loading the image in an img-element with:

```
<img src="{% static "images/start1.JPG" %}" alt="My image">
```

That worked, so the image is there at the right path.

Best,
Lennie.

The option with the " is interpreted into html like this:

```
style='background-image: url("{% static \"images/start1.JPG\"}");
```

Comment: Did you try: `<li style="background-image: url({% static "images/start1.JPG" %})">`.
You don't need to use html entities or extra escaping inside the `{% %}` tag. Quotes inside the tag are parsed independently from quotes outside the curly braces.
 And check the rendered html output from your django template. That will typically give you a clue about what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, but am getting a Syntax Error, so the page won't load. I checked it, the best solution so far I get with the &quot; option, which produces:
style='background-image: url("{% static \"images/start1.JPG\"}");'

But it added the backslashes and I think that's what's bothering.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the error. I had the command {% load staticfiles %} in my base.html file.

And I was extending that template, but apparently I needed to put that command also in my index.html file.